# declaring global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

So I have the following code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: appID, xfbml: true, status: true, cookie: true});
}   

...some lines of code

function anotherFunction()
{
    FB.ui(blah,blah);
}
```

`FB.ui` throws me a `ReferenceError:FB is not defined`. This wasnt happening before I wrapped `FB.init` inside `window.fbAsyncInit`, which I have to in order to init FB correctly. How can I make FB get recognized inside `anotherFunction`?

FB is the facebook library. The init function is supposed to initialize and set it globally. The `var FB;` line wasnt there initially. I only added it to check if that will remove the error, because the error was already there

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is `anotherFunction` called? The point of the `fbAsyncInit` wrapper is to make sure the Facebook SDK has loaded.

Comment: I know that is what fbAsyncInit is for, which is why I used it. anotherFunction is called in the same page if a button is clicked. So FB.init runs first when the page is loaded, and if user clicks on a button then anotherFunction is fired.

Comment: Nowhere in your code have you written `FB = something;`. Include the part of your code where you actually initialize FB. You can't call `FB.init()` if FB has not been initialized.

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/3wQu4/

Comment: FB is the Facebook library. FB.init is a call to their SDK library

Comment: Ah. Well you overwrote FB with an empty variable of your own by declaring `var FB;`. Could that be your problem?

Comment: no I added that because I was checking if then anotherFunction will recognize FB. It was not there initially

Comment: That's right, and FB is set globally once the SDK is loaded, and placing it inside a function seems to work splendidly in the Fiddle above, so you must be doing something wrong. I'd tend to agree with @John above here, why do you define FB as "undefined" in your code, you shouldn't mess with the FB variable at all.

Comment: check my comment above..

Comment: Try placing the event handler function inside FBinit as well, like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/3wQu4/1/, and see what happens

Comment: FB.init is working fine because when the page loads, that function runs and if I console.log FB then I do get a Facebook object correctly.

Comment: Then how the heck are you getting undefined ?

Comment: No freaking idea.... :(

Comment: So if you console.log FB you get the facebook object, but if you console log FB inside the event handler, you get undefined? You must be either out of scope for some reason, and you could try `window.FB.ui()` to confirm that theory, or you somehow defined FB as "undefined" between the init and the time the button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to initialize the variable somehow ?
You seem to be calling 'init' on a null value...

Comment: FB is undefined, var FB = {};

Comment: However, that won't fix your code, it seems FB is a library from another framework